# Android Studio - Trouble setting off notifications with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, notificationmanager

So my program is supposed to set off a notification a few hours after the application has been stopped (minutes are being used just now for testing). It does this, however the problem with it is that if the code is executed a second time before a notification has been pushed, then no notification is pushed at all.

```
Override
public void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int alarmTime = (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + 3;
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,alarmTime);

    Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),timeReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent3,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent3);
}
@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();
    //this.onCreate(null);
}
```

This is what my broadcast receiver class looks like...

```
public class timeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
    builder.setContentTitle("Timer Notification");
    builder.setContentText("blaaah blaaah blah");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

}
}
```

My expectation is that the alarm would reset and trigger 3 minutes after the last execution of the onStop() method, but this does not happen. I don't really understand why it doesn't, if anyone could give me insight/ a possible solution I would be grateful. Also the SDK version is 24.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your notification with `NotificationCompat.Builder#setWhen(long)`, no need for alarm manager.

Comment: I've attempted to schedule my notification with the NotificationCompat builder but the notification just triggers straight away. Is there something wrong with my code? I'll post it below in the answers section. This is in the onStop() method.

Comment: did you use `setWhen(timestamp)`?

Comment: For example, you have to use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + (60000)` to have it fire in 1 minute.

Comment: yeah, I've tried inserting 'builder.setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + (60000));' and the notification still fires as soon as the stop code is run.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int notification1Id = 56748;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int alarmTime = (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + 2;

    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,alarmTime);
    long timeMs = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Build notifications
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
    builder.setContentTitle("It's been a while...");
    builder.setContentText("Remember to keep track of your calories using the calorie counter");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setWhen(timeMs);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notification1Id, builder.build());
```